# Rails not finding record by ID, even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that displays the games in an NFL week. So, if the user navigates to: url.com/week/1/ it will display all of the games.

The format is: /week/:id

The controller looks like this:

```
def show
    @week = Week.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.first #place holder until current_user is implemented
    @games = @week.games
end
```

When I go to check the page I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WeekController#show
Couldn't find Week with 'id'=

Extracted source (around line #154):
152
153
154
155
156
157

        record = s.execute([id], self, connection).first
        unless record
          raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#    {primary_key}'=#{id}"
        end
        record
      rescue RangeError
```

The id is blank, though I don't understand why, because it's in the parameters:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"4"}
```

I can verify using the rails console that this record/week should exist, but rails can't find it for some reason... this was working fine and all of a sudden stopped working when I added some validations to another model, but I don't see how they can be related. This is a really simple query.

Any thoughts?

edit: Trace included below:

```
app/models/pick.rb:31:in `pick_within_range'
app/controllers/week_controller.rb:16:in `block in show'
app/controllers/week_controller.rb:11:in `show'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:154:in `find'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations.rb:395:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in `valid?'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in `valid?'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:83:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Full backtrace please - might be some gem doings.

Comment: Broi: Hope that's what you meant by backtrace, still learning :)

Comment: how does your game model look?

Comment: This is at the top of your backtrace: app/models/pick.rb:31:in `pick_within_range'. What's going on in that method?  Also, the error message states: "Couldn't find Week with 'id'= ". Note there is no value after 'id'= . This suggests the value you are passing in is not what you think it is.

Comment: Doug, you hit the nail on the head there, I was forgetting to pass my @week instance variable to a method, and it was causing this error. I thought this was all happening with the first sql query and got distracted... my mistake everyone, thanks for the help. I'll pay closer attention to the trace next time.